# Design to store query in object form

Tags: c#, sql, oop, design-patterns

We are building an application where we need to store Query in object form like:

```
    class Query{
     public Select s{get;set;}
     public From f{get;set;}
    }
    class select {
     public List< Column > columns {get;set;}

    }
    class Column{
     public string ColumnName {get;set;}
     public string AliasName {get;set;}
    }
    class From {
     public Table mainTable{get;set;}
     public List<JoinTable>{get;set;}
    }
    class Table {
     public string tableName{get;set;}
     public string Alias{get;set;}
    }
    class JoinTable:Table{
     public string OnExpression{get;set;}
    }
```

we are storing details in these objects so later on we can create queries for any database using these objects.It can be even more complex with subquery also. Please let me know if there is any better design to do so.

Note: We are using C# to develop this application.

Answer (score 0):

There is always room for improvement and since "better" has a different meaning for each of us, I will focus only on the provable improvements. Since there is always room for improvement, this list is not a complete nor final list:

1. Since sub-queries with named tables are possible, you will need to support queries of this form:

`select c1, c2
 from (select c3 as c1, c4 as c2 from yourtable) renamedtable;`

2. You need to allow sorting
3. You need to allow grouping
4. You need to allow paging, that is, loading a finite number of records starting from an offset

These are just comments on your ORM, but you might have expressions you might want to reuse. You might want to be able to store those. Also, you might want to be able to generate classes for the tables you have in an arbitrary database. LINQ is a perequisite, you might want to look through its features and contemplate whether you want those and if so, how will those fit into your situation.

Comment: Thanks @Lajos for your inputs I'll go through your suggestion but i am not building ORM instead of that i am working on a Query generator that can store query in object form and can execute it on any db.

Comment: @yashpal I thought that was the long-term plan. Since it is not, it seems I was wrong about that. Anyway, I wish you the best of luck with your project.